# port 22: connection refused

Tags: ssh, mac-osx

I am new to OSX, and I am trying to remotely log onto a computer at my school from home. My friend showed me how to use ssh and I was successfully able to log into the computer while I was working with him. When I went home, I got this error:

```
port 22: Connection refused
```

I tried looking at other posts, but like I said, I'm not used to OSX and I can't figure out what might be wrong--the only thing that I can find are for Linux machines, and I'm running Mavericks on a Macbook Pro. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a Mac problem, its to do with the network to the computer you're trying to connect to.

1. Is it in a LAN, or publicly (internet) visible. If in a LAN, you can't connect to that machine when you are at home because the machine is in a different LAN, unless you get a link to the public domain.
2. Is ssh enabled for the user e.g. root (or the one you connecting with) in the ssh config file of the machine you want to connect to (you did not specify the OS on the 'school computer': if its Linux then follow the guide to "refuse remote ssh for root" on google?
3. Lastly, is ssh disabled outside the LAN.

All these can be factors, you just need to ask yourself question 1 above, or understand the ssh configuration made on that PC to see if its not one of the factors I mentionedfor question 2 and 3. Good Luck.